# Update bootstrap datetimepicker after every step/click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm using [this extension of Bootstrap's datepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). It works well enough, but I've come upon a usability issue - when selecting a date/time, the text field the datepicker is attached to does not update unless all the steps (year/month/day/hour/minute) are selected to the end. Clicking away from the datepicker before clicking all the steps yields no change to the date in the text field.

How do I make it so that when the user clicks away mid-selection (maybe because they just want to change the date, but find the already-present hour and minute to be acceptable), the text field is updated appropriately?

For example:

Initial date in field: 2015/10/10 10:00

Click on 2015/10/15 -> click away -> date in field: 2015/10/15 10:00

Is that even possible?

Comment: you may want to look at the [events](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker#events) section

Comment: I looked at that. 'hide' triggers when I want it to, but I'm unsure how to use that to change the date in the field to the one currently selected.

Comment: on [change date](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker#changedate) apply the [update](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker#update) method

Comment: Nope. It fires only after you click through all the steps.

Comment: I've also tried a 'hide' event with the update method, but the event date points to the date in the text field, not as last clicked.

Comment: @JPPK can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4cqLcxcm/3/ Note how it doesn't update the input field until you've clicked through all the choices.

Answer (score 0):

Check this updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/4cqLcxcm/8/

Added on changeDay event on datepicker, which will trigger on change of date and set that value into input box.
Below is the code I have changed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var now = new Date();
       $('#send-time').datetimepicker({
           format: 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:ii',
           startDate: now
       })
       .on('changeDay', function(ev){
           $('#send-time').datetimepicker('update',ev.date);
       });
    console.log('test'); 
});
```

Comment: Why does it add two hours per day to the time, in addition to changing the day?

Comment: Or, well, one hour per day on day selection. Something screwy is going on with that. I can compensate programmatically, though.

Comment: Scratch that. The behaviour of the datepicker in this approaches 'undefined'. Why isn't 'changeDay' documented?